# How to set different functionalities to different users in a Telegram bot using node js

Tags: node.js, module, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I am new to Node.js and the Telegraf library. I'm trying to build a Telegram bot with different functionalities for different users. For example, the client won't have the same /help command as the admin or the employees.

I have tried setting up modules for each user type, but the problem is that the bot uses the type of the first user who starts the bot, and every other user gets the same functionalities.

For example, if I started the admin first and then a client, the client would get all of the admin's commands and wouldn't get their own commands. The opposite should be correct.
this is the main module

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");
const clientRoutes = require("./client");
const adminRoutes = require("./admin");

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TELEGRAM_TOKEN1);
const ownerId = Number(process.env.OWNER_ID);

bot.start((ctx) => {
  let userId = ctx.from.id;

  console.log(userId);
  console.log(ownerId);
  if (userId === ownerId) {
    adminRoutes.setup(bot, ctx); // Set up admin functionality for the bot owner
  } else {
    clientRoutes.setup(bot, ctx); // Set up client functionality for all other users
  }
});

bot.launch();
```

And this is the client module (the admin module is the same at the moment, just replacing "client" with "admin").

```
function setup(bot, ctx) {
  bot.command("help", (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("This is a client command.");
  });


  console.log("Client functionality set up for user with ID:", ctx.from.id);
}

module.exports = { setup };
```